# Visual Studio 2010 - Application not starting up through asp.NET Development Server but works on the Production Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am building a .NET 4.0 Web Forms application in C#. After working for around 4-5 months on this application, the other day when I went to 'Start' the application from Visual Studio 2010 and the application does not want to start. When trying to connect using telnet on the local host and that port, it connects, and after a while I get an error '400 - Bad Request'.

The funny thing is that when I Publish the application on another IIS server, it works fine, it seems like the problem is from the asp.NET Development Server. While I know that I can set-up a local IIS, I would prefer not to avoid doing this in order to avoid certain problems which might be related to having a different configuration of the local IIS from production.

I have checked the hosts file, re-installed visual studio and confirmed that the application works when published. I have also checked that the port is not being used by another process.

What else should I check?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/core-differences-between-iis-and-the-asp-net-development-server-vb

Comment: check whether the behaviour is the same when you use the Visual Studio Development Server, Local IIS, or IIS Express (this is set on the Web tab of your project properties)

Comment: Do you have installed the fiddler tool in your local machine ? If not, download and install it captures the request and what the port has been blocked.

Answer (score 1):

If the application will not start, then the odds of you being able to connect to it via telnet on a port are 0.  (It's not running.)

I am assuming the application can compile if you can publish it. Have you tried running the application without debugging?  CTRL + F5